# Alfresco amp to war: Unable to load module details from property file

Tags: jar, cmd, alfresco, alfresco-share, module-management

This is like the 18th time I have this error. Somehow I always manage to fix it but this time I cant fix it..
When I try the following command in CMD to load my AMP file into my alfresco.war (with the module management tool) I get the following error:

My CMD command:

```
 C:\Alfresco\bin>java -jar alfresco-mmt.jar install 
 C:\Users\Rob\workspace\amp\target\amp.amp  C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco.war
```

I get this error:

Unable to load module details from property file.

please any help is good :)

Comment: Try it with a default Alfresco amp, like sharepoint spp/vti to test. Maybe there's something wrong within your amp.

Comment: Does your AMP have a `module.properties` file in it, and is it a valid Java properties file?

Comment: it seems my amp structure is wrong, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that the problem is in the path of the module.amp file. Ensure that the absolute path of the amp file is right in your bat.